# When an object is added, why does it fall through the grid?

Tags: mesh

I thought the grid is the surface of where everything takes place and stands on.

Comment: The grid is a visual guide, nothing more. It has no physical presence in your scene

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos  I understand that it's not physical but since it is a guide, the logical thing is to use it as an illusion of physical ground and place objects accordingly. I don't know why by default objects spawn at the centre of the 3d space but I want uhm the bottom of whatever object I create to be touching the grid with it's tip. You know what I mean? How do I do that with every object? and how do I make that a default coordinate for spawning objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid is not a floor or ground. It is not even an object. It is just a guide so that users can see the units used in the scene and to have a visual representation of the horizontal coordinates.

All objects have what is called an origin (a pivot point or a "center", usually represented by an orange dot) The origin of the the created object is then placed where the 3D cursor is on the scene. By default the cursor is at coordinate 0, 0, 0.

[image]

In other words, by default the object's center is placed at the center of the 3D space.

[image]

To have your objects appear in a different place, just move the 3D cursor.

[image]

Comment: So how do I make objects appear by default so the tip of the bottom of each object touches the imaginary surface of the grid? and how do I keep that as a default coordinate?

Comment: you can move the 3d cursor (as explained in the answer). But moving it one blender unit in the Z axis will work only for objects that are two units tall. Blender works better with objects that are modeled in a size that resembles dimensions in the real world. So depending on the object you are modeling  you might need to place the 3d cursor in different places. As a loose rule of thumb place the 3d cursor at half the height of the total height of the new object.

Comment: I don't really understand this part "will work only for objects that are two units tall. Blender works better with objects that are modeled in a size that resembles dimensions in the real world. As a loose rule of thumb place the 3d cursor at half the height of the total height of the new object. " but I think I found my solution: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143520/how-do-i-make-sure-my-objects-are-always-touching-the-grid-floor/143522?noredirect=1#comment244952_143522  What do you say?

Comment: You need to read more carefully...The comment reads *But moving it **one** blender unit in the Z axis will work only for objects that are two units tall.* In the example above I moved the 3D cursor one unit in the Z axis, and then added a sphere that is two units in diameter. That way the center of the object will be at Z1.00, and the bottom part of the object will be at  0. Again "*place the 3d cursor at half the height of the total height of the new object*". But I feel I'm repeating myself...

Comment: Finally I understood it... Now I have written down 3 ways of doing this. yey :3 Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The center of your object is added at the cursor's position. If you haven't changed it, it's set to (0, 0, 0). So parts of your object are above 0, some are below (for the z axis, but it's the same with x and y).

And the center (called origin) is by default set to the geometry center, not what you would probably call the "bottom" of your object.

Comment: I understand that it's not physical but since it is a guide, the logical thing is to use it as an illusion of physical ground and place objects accordingly. I don't know why by default objects spawn at the centre of the 3d space but I want uhm the bottom of whatever object I create to be touching the grid with it's tip. You know what I mean? How do I do that with every object? and how do I make that a default coordinate for spawning objects?

Comment: Well it has to create them somewhere :)