# How do I make sure my objects are always touching the grid floor?

Tags: coordinates

I want to use the grid as an imaginary floor.

Is there a mathematical operation to make sure that no matter the length of the object that the bottom of the object is always touching the grid?

Apparently the grid is on 0,0,0 xyz coordinates. If I place my object on the same coordinates it just slashes my object in half. I don't want that. I want the bottom to be on that coordinate.

[image]

---

HA HA! I was going ask this but I think I'm on to it.

What I did is I've gone to edit mode, chose to only select vertex points, selected a bottom vertex point. Copied the Z axis location which was -3.22222 then, I've chosen to select the whole object with <kbd>A</kbd>, and just turned that - into a + for the z axis of the whole object and voila we've got a winner.

Someone tell me if this is the correct way or if there's a different way.

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways. If your object has a bottom face that is supposed to touch the plane on z = 0, you select that face in edit mode, call <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, cursor to selection. 
Then switch to object mode and change your object's origin by selecting origin to 3D cursor, as shown here:

[image]

Then, still in object mode, you can move your object to z = 0 by entering the value directly into the coordinates box.

[image]

Comment: hold up, don't I need to calculate where to place my 3d cursor? that would still requiere me to do the same steps I actually did originally in my post just to find out the exact coordinates where to place the object? I don't get this way :S

Comment: You don't. When you select the face, do cursor to selection, it positions itself at the center of the face. Now I'm assuming your face has no z dimension which seems to be the case in your example. In the way I'm describing the 3D cursor is there only to change the origin point of your object. Once it's done, your object is all above the origin, so you can position it (position its origin really) at z = 0.

Comment: Huh, I don't think I understood a thing lol. But if you agree that the way I did it is correct then I'll keep doing it like that

Comment: I didn't really agree :). It's about what works anyway, so your method is probably fine, although you have to calculate stuff, which sometimes is difficult.

Comment: Alright lol, I'll deal with numbers since I can't understand blender terminology. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I'm back, I somewhat understand now what you mean however I don't have the option to set origin when in edit mode, only in object mode and I don't have the option to select a face in object mode so theres the problem...

Comment: In edit mode, set cursor so selected (after selecting the face. I'd select both downmost faces in your mesh so the origin is well-centered). Then in object mode, set origin to 3D cursor.

Comment: I got it thanks a lot :D could you please modify this part of your main post "Then change your object's origin by selecting origin to 3D cursor, as shown here:" to "Then switch and stay in object mode to change your object's origin by selecting origin to 3D cursor, as shown here:" It will be more helpful to people who come by the post :)

Comment: @Pf22 you can edit the asnwers too.